# I am trying to display a block image on hover but just cant get it; with css3 and Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

before anything, this is my codepen, I am trying to pretty much hover over that and make it say about me. Ive tried a few things but it is just not clicking.

this is my link

http://codepen.io/willc86/pen/BrEmt

I was hoping someone can help explain to me how to change this to a solid background color (lets say all red) with font white saying "about me"

is it possible w/o JavaScript?

Comment: Change what, to what? It's just an image that scales ?

Comment: Are you wanting the scaling box to change to a red color with text inside?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to apply the hover on something higher up.

You can't hover over something invisible. However, you can hover over the things which hold the invisible item.

So, instead of doing something like:

```
.hidden:hover { visibility: visible; }
```

Instead, put it on a parent element, like the li:

```
li:hover .hidden { visibility: visible; }
```

Now, when you hover over the li that contains the hidden item, the hidden item appears.

Now it's just a matter of tweaking that container to give you exactly what you want. =)